# Passing argument to a method if not null

Tags: python

How do i include argument in python only if its not null? Following code works fine if i pass valid color to method doSomething. Now color is sometimes null (like null in java, i guess its None or nil in python), whic is when printColor throws exception. How can i avoid this?

`Invalid type for parameter packageNamespace, value: None`

```
response = client.printColor(
            color = color # Only include this param is not None/Null
   )

response = client.printColor() # this works
```

Comment: You could just check for None and dispatch to the correct call of the function. If you wanted to get crazy, something like this may work `arg = if color [color] else []; response = client.printColor(*arg)`, but I can't see much benefit there.

Comment: `response = client.printColor(color) if color is not None else client.printColor()`

Comment: Does `client.printColor` belong to some public package whose documentation we can look at?

Comment: This was a sample method, the actual method has tons of params which can be null. So i cant write code for every possible combination.  Looking for something generic.

Comment: @user93796 Can you modify the `client.printColor` method?

Comment: And what do you want to happen if an arg is null? If the method takes 5 parameters, and 3 of the arguments are null, do you just want to apply the 2 as the two first parameters? Does it have default parameters?

Comment: This sounds like a poorly designed API, why can't you just pass `None`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter `None`s out of a dict:

```
kwargs = {
    'color': color,
    ⋮
}

response = client.printColor(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
```

Or do the same thing as a function:

```
def none_to_default(**kwargs):
    return {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}


client.printColor(**none_to_default(
    color=color,
    ⋮
))
```

This might not be the best solution to the problem, though. It would be ideal if you could show the real function[’s documentation].